# Sums of nonzero triangular numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

OEIS [A002097](http://oeis.org/A002097) gives numbers that are not the sum of 3 nonzero triangular numbers. They are just seven numbers: 1, 2, 4, 6, 11, 20, 29.

The site says that the seven numbers are all without references. Could you let me know the reference or proof?

Comment: Just for fun : the sum of these seven numbers is equal to  $ 73 $ , which can be written  $ p_{t_{t_{t_{p_{1}}}}} $ .

Comment: I don't see how one could prove that with current technology.  If we multiply by $8$ and add $3$, then one must write $8n+3$ as a sum of three squares (which are all necessarily odd) and the number of representations of this grows like a class number.  On the other hand, we want to throw away the number of representations where one of the squares equals $1$ -- this is roughly the number of ways of writing $8n+2$ as a sum of two squares, which could grow like a divisor function.  So this problem looks to me of a comparable difficulty to the Euler idoneal number problem.

Comment: Of course the previous comment does show that there are only finitely many exceptions, and one can also bound the number of exceptions.  However it is not clear how one could determine a complete list unconditionally.

Comment: @Lucia Yes, I agree that's not clear. So I guessed someone wrote a paper about it.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90914/sums-of-three-non-zero-squares for the question of sums of three nonzero squares.

Comment: Ono, Robins, Wahl's paper https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01831114 yields the number $\delta_k(n)$ of representations of $n$ as sums of $k$ triangular numbers. But the formula does not solve the problem.